# Why does my remote MongoDB connection require authentication on every query?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, bottle

After fighting with different things here and there, I was finally able to get [BottlePY](http://bottle.paws.de/) running on Apache and run a MongoDB powered site. I am used to running Django apps, so I will be relating to that a bit in my question.

**The Problem**

Every time a page is loaded via BottlePY, the connection to the MongoDB database located on MongoHQ.com needs to be re-authenticated (meaning it probably had to reconnect).

**What I Found**

I attached a `db.keep_alive()` function to the top of each model function, so that before any mongodb query is run, it trys to run a simple query. If it fails, it catches the OperationFailure or AutoReconnect errors and then calls the `db.authenticate()` function. After it reauthenticates, I have it add a log to a logs db to monitor how often it needs to reauthenticate. Currently, it needs to reauthenticate on every page load (that requires running a query). This isn't right.

**Difference from Django**

I use this same concept in django, and have found that the db connection only needs to be authenticated after 10-15 minutes of no queries being run.

I don't understand why creating a pymongo connection in django would be different from creating one in bottle, since I am using the same driver, functions and methods. I am not using any ORMS or anything like that either.

**Versions**

- Bottle: *0.9.dev*
- Django: *1.2.1 final*
- PyMongo: *1.8*

I appreciate the help!

Update: A friend was able to take a quick look and noticed the following that may help with answering my question.

> It appears that each request is
>   launching a new Python process, as
>   opposed to Django, in which a single
>   process remains running for a long
>   period of time.

Comment: You have to authenticate as many times as is the number of your worker processes. You can't reuse database connections across processes. So the first think you have to solve in your framework (independently of MongoDB), that there are only a few number of processes (in a worker pool) in your framework serving your requests. os.getpid() should return only a few disjoint values.

Comment: how do you run your python inside apache:
via mod_python or wsgi ?

Comment: @pts Thanks! I am looking into this.


@ralf.w. WSGI on Apache2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This just ended up to be a weird thing between Bottle and MongoHQ. No real solution was found, but I couldn't recreate it with other frameworks. Any other ideas are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

does your apache xxx.conf contain something like:

`WSGIDaemonProcess project user=mysite group=www-data processes=5 threads=1
 WSGIProcessGroup project`

I think most important should be `threads=1`

Comment: It was set to 10 but I changed it to 1 and it hasn't solved the problem. Good point though, thanks!

Comment: Also try setting both processes=1 and threads=1 and see if the problem goes away. Please note that this should be only a temporary setting for debugging, because it limits the number of concurrent connections your web application can handle.